# Can anyone get the new marketplace drag n' drop to work with Eclipse Indigo?

Tags: eclipse, drag-and-drop, eclipse-indigo

I am on a new mac and cannot get eclipse to install marketplace plugins by dragging n' dropping them onto eclipse.  I have tried using both Safari and Firefox, but neither of them work.

Is there a certain place/section they have to be dropped to, or is there an alternative way to install the plugins?

Without the emacs+ plugin I am useless.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For me on Windows, I can get drag-n-drop to work if I drop on the menu/toolbar area or some views. It doesn't work for drops on the editor area or some of the views that define their own drag-n-drop behaviors.

Try Help -> Eclipse Marketplace if you cannot get drag-n-drop to work. Search and install from that dialog.

Comment: I have tried dropping the plugin on ever possible gui component, but nothing works.  As for the marketplace link it no longer exists for me in the Help menu.

Comment: What Eclipse package did you download? It sounds like you are missing Marketplace Client completely in your installation.

Comment: I downloaded and installed the eclipse classic 3.7.  I tried it on my home computer and get the same thing.  Seems like a giant bug to me.

Comment: I haven't checked it in a while, but I don't believe that Eclipse Classic ever contained Marketplace Client. The "classic" part pretty much constrains the features to what was originally available in the original "Eclipse SDK". Try another package, such as Eclipse IDE for Java Developers.

Comment: That was it.  The only reason I downloaded classic is that was what was recommended on the google site, but the Java version also works and has the market place.

Comment: It is funny why Eclipse advertises features that don't work at all!

Answer (score 2):

The drag and drop option does not work for IE. I would suggest using Chrome. I experienced the same issue a few times. from other browsers.

Comment: It doesn't work from Firfox either, so surely Chrome is a safe bet

Answer (score 1):

Go to HELP---> Install new software-->copy paste your plugin site url in work with text box--> click add.. there you go.. just follow installation steps and you are done. Enjoy your plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using Eclipse Juno on a Mac and could not get the drag and drop to work. What worked for me was (in Eclipse) Help menu, Install new software.... then I selected the Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno option from the list box and was able to find the plugin I was looking for.

Answer (score -3):

It's so simple. Click Help, Install From Catalog (it will create marketplace window). Now you have lots of plugins to install.